# Sql Server: return a row from a query only if it is unique

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server I'd like to be able to return a result form my query if there is an exact match, i.e. I only match on one row, and if there isn't I'd like to return no result at all.

I realize it's fairly easy to handle this in code, once the sql query has returned, but I'd like to be able to do the test in Sql Server, if it's achievable reasonably easily.

Comment: What am I missing here?  You just want to put a where clause in your select statement and run it in Management Studio.  If it finds the exact match based on your where, it will turn a record.  If not, it won't return anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you ONLY want to get the data back if you match one and only one record.

One way to do this is to use an intermediate result set and `COUNT` or `@@ROWCOUNT`

You can put your results into a `#TEMP` table or `@Table` variable, then inspect either that table or the `@@ROWCOUNT` variable to determine if you got one row back.  If you do, return the intermediate result set.

Comment: Using COUNT() OVER you wouldn't need a temporary table, but as COUNT() OVER is not available before the 2005 version, your method is more universal.

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server 2005 or later version, you can use `COUNT() OVER` like this:

```
WITH matches AS (
  SELECT
    ...,
    TotalMatches = COUNT(*) OVER ()
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
)
SELECT *
FROM matches
WHERE TotalMatches = 1
;
```

The `matches` CTE finds all rows matching the main requirement and returns them along with the total count of matches. The main query returns the found results only if the additional requirement, total match count of 1, is satisfied.

Comment: +1 - I always like seeing something done in one step if possible :)